# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql

Este es el fragmento que me tira el error

```php
case "Agregar":
        $sentenciaSQL=$conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO palabra (palabraE, palabraG, ejemplo, sinonimo, significado) VALUES (:español, :guarani, :ejemplo, :sinonimo, :significado);");
        $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(":español", $palabraE);
        $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(":guarani", $palabraGua);
        $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(":ejemplo", $Ejemplo);
        $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(":sinonimo", $Sinonimo);
        $sentenciaSQL->bindParam(":significado", $Significado);
        $sentenciaSQL->execute();
        echo 'Presionado boton agregar';
        break;
```

Esta es mi conexion

```php
<?php

    $host = 'localhost';
    $db = 'diccionarios';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    try {
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $user, $pass);
        //echo "Conectado con exito!";
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo'<p>No se puede conectar a la base de datos!!</p>';
        exit;
    }return $conexion;
?>
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que es en ese trozo de código que te aparece ese error?  Por lo que parece no debería salirte eso, sino mas bien el `echo'<p>No se puede conectar a la base de datos!!</p>';`  porque estás recogiendo la excepción e impidiendo su salida para mostrar ese echo, ¿no?

Comment: ¿En qué archivo y en qué número de línea te dice que está el error? Puede que el uso de la `ñ` esté causando problemas en tu código, suele ocurrir si no configuras bien la codificación.

Comment: esta es la ubicacion de donde me tira el error y el case está ubicado en productos C:\xampp1\htdocs\asd2\administrador\seccion\productos.php(24): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in
C:\xampp1\htdocs\asd2\administrador\seccion\productos.php
on line
24

Comment: @Elias Prueba, como sugiere A. Cedano, cambiando el nombre de este parámetro: `$sentenciaSQL->bindParam(":español", $palabraE);`  (cámbiale la **ñ** por una **n** por ejemplo), y tambien lo debes cambiar aquí: `VALUES (:español,` para que sean iguales.  Ya nos dirás si con eso se arregla o estamos igual.

Comment: Si, era la ñ, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Cuando trabajas con base de datos en un contexto PHP/HTML debes ser cuidadoso con la codificación si tu contenido tiene acentos o carácteres especiales. El problema es que PHP/HTML podrían interpretar mal esos carácteres si la codificación no está bien configurada.

¿Cómo evitarlo?

- Donde sea posible, evita esos caracteres (nombres de tablas, nombres de columnas, nombres de variables). Podrías incluso optar por una convención de nombre en inglés. Las ventajas son varias: el inglés te permite escribir variables menos verbosas (más cortas), y permite la internacionalización del código, aspecto nada despreciable en proyectos más o menos grandes en el que podrían participar varios programadores o en proyectos que quieras compartir en el futuro, como una API, un complemento, etc que quieras exponer al público.
- Donde no sea posible (contenido de las tablas) aplica en la definición de las tablas/columnas una codificación adecuada. Del mismo modo, configura bien el entorno: el documento HTML, la configuración de PHP, la conexión <sup>1</sup>.

Aplicando lo dicho, el código podría quedar así (cambio, por el momento, aquello que se puede cambiar, sin riesgo):

```
case "Agregar":
        $stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO palabra (palabraE, palabraG, ejemplo, sinonimo, significado) VALUES (:es, :gn, :example, :synonymous, :signification);");
        $stmt->bindParam(":es", $esWord);
        $stmt->bindParam(":gn", $gnWord);
        $stmt->bindParam(":example", $example);
        $stmt->bindParam(":synonymous", $synonymous);
        $stmt->bindParam(":signification", $signification);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo 'Presionado boton agregar';
        break;
```

En la programación hay unos **estándares** que conviene usar, son breves y cualquier programador (de PHP en este caso) al verlos sabrá de lo que estamos hablando. En el código anterior he usado dos: `$stmt` se usa para el objeto que representa a una consulta preparada y `$conn` se usa para el objeto que representa a la conexión (otra posibilidad es  `$db` pero esa ya la usaste para el nombre de la base de datos, o `$pdo` para el caso de PDO). Parece una estupidez, pero el simple uso de `$stmt` aquí, en vez del kilométrico `$sentenciaSQL` mejora muchísimo la calidad/legibilidad del código.

Hay otros estándares. Por ejemplo, [para los lenguajes existe el estándar ISO](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php), que asigna unas pocas letras a cada lenguaje y que se puede usar aquí, hablando de un programa que trabaja con lenguajes. Ese estándar ha definido `es` para *Español*  y `gn` para *Guaraní*.

En cuanto a la conexión, podemos indicar el charset en el DSN, basta con agregar esto al final: `;charset=UTF8`. Esto te evitará muchos problemas con los datos. Por lo dicho más arriba, he cambiado el nombre de la conexión a `$conn`.

```
<?php

    $host = 'localhost';
    $db = 'diccionarios';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=UTF8", $user, $pass);
        //echo "Conectado con exito!";
        return $conn;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo'<p>No se puede conectar a la base de datos!!</p>';
        return null;
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Puede que en algunos contextos esto no sea suficiente y debas hacer otras configuraciones a nivel de base de datos, de HTML o de PHP. Para más detalles consulta la **Nota**.

#### Nota:

1. Para profundizar sobre una solución definitiva al problema de la codificación puedes consultar [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/29967) a la pregunta: *[¿Por que el Carácter inspector (�) aparece en algunos datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/59489/29967)*.